# JavaFX fxml not launching/doing anything

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml

I have built a GUI using scene builder, through eclipse.

I am trying to run the MainApp class to view the GUI in eclipse, everything compiles, there are no error messages in the console, a java process opens but nothing actually happens and no window is created on screen.

I have been through oracle's site and attempted to alter the code but nothing works. I have updated java, reinstalled javafx etc in eclipse. I also tried the program throuhg netbeans to the same effect.

Running on MacOS X

```
package main;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(MainApp.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
`package main;
```

The controller class

```
public class Controller implements Initializable  {

@FXML
Button checkButton;
@FXML
Button callButton;
@FXML
Button raiseButton;
@FXML
Button foldButton;


public void buttonClicked() {
    System.out.println("Button was clicked");
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
}
```

The FXML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="main.Controller">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29949874686716793" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="67.0" prefHeight="433.0" prefWidth="800.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="67.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <LineChart layoutY="206.0" prefHeight="215.0" prefWidth="235.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
                  <LineChart prefHeight="215.0" prefWidth="235.0">
                    <xAxis>
                      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                    </xAxis>
                    <yAxis>
                      <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                    </yAxis>
                  </LineChart>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.6783216783216783" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="498.0" prefWidth="555.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <items>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="127.0" prefWidth="553.0">
                           <children>
                              <TextArea disable="true" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="23.0" prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="536.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="9.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="23.0" />
                              <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Live guidance:" />
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </items>
                  </SplitPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
      <ImageView fitHeight="62.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="5.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../../Desktop/Dissertation%20files/logo.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ButtonBar layoutX="456.0" layoutY="16.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <buttons>
          <Button fx:id="checkButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" onMouseClicked="#buttonClicked" style="-fx-background-radius: 10;" text="Check" />
            <Button fx:id="callButon" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" onMouseClicked="#buttonClicked" style="-fx-background-radius: 10;" text="Call" />
            <Button fx:id="raiseButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" onMouseClicked="#buttonClicked" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="81.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 10;" text="Raise" />
            <Button fx:id="foldButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClicked" onMouseClicked="#buttonClicked" style="-fx-background-radius: 10;" text="Fold" />
        </buttons>
      </ButtonBar>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Apologies if I am missing something simple.

Comment: It works fine for me. (I assume the missing `}` in `MainApp` and the extra one in `Controller` are simply copy and paste errors.)

Comment: Where is your GUI.fxml file located? Inside folder or package, or in the root of dir?

Comment: @James_D yes apologies, first time really using stackoverflow so my bad.

Comment: @NwDx  It's in the same package as the Controller + MainApp classes, along with a bunch of other poker related classes (Deck, Card, HandEvaluator etcetera). I did try playing about with the getResource() parameter to no avail?

Answer (score 0):

If the classes and the fxml file is under same package then the loader line should be like this

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/package_name/fxml2GUI.fxml"));
```

Put your source's package name in the place of "packagename"